# How to correctly reorder the list using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a small program where I will reorder the list following a sequence by it's minimal changes. I only want to show the number of changes made. This is my Code:

```
n, k = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
store_1 = range(a[0],a[0]+(n*k),k)
store_2 = []
for y in store_1:
    if y not in a:
       store_2.append(y)
print(len(store_2))
```

The program here is to output the minimum ways to reorder the list. The list is to be reordered following the sequence set on 'k'.For some cases I have made, the program seems to be working fine. For example:

```
In: 6 2
In: 1 2 5 7 9 85
Out: 2
```

Cases like this seems to be working, since 'k' is set to 2 the list must follow the sequence of 2. So the least changes that can be made is to change 2 = 3, and 85 = 11.

But for some tough cases I have made, my code is well off the mark. For example:

```
In: 8 1
In: 1 1 4 5 6 7 11 12
Out: 3
```

But that's a completely wrong output because those changes are not possible. The best change that can be made is `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` with 4 changes.

How can I make my code to efficiently and correctly reorder the lists following the sequence?

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to reorder the list following the sequence directly? Like: Instead going through all that why not iterate through the list and replace it with the correct sequence number to be followed and count the changes made?

Comment: Shouldn't the second example change to `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`?

Comment: @user1093967 no because it will mean 7 changes, I am looking for the minimum changes to reorder the array.

Comment: @mahir I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. In the first example, it looked like you were trying to transform `a` to `store_1`. Can you explain what you're trying to do in more depth (and how `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` is an answer for the second example)?